# How to capture stdout from multiple programs in bash function?

Tags: bash

I have a bash function defined like:

```
$ test() { ./compile $1 ${1::-4}.output; ./simulate < ${1::-4}.output; }
```

Running this function produces the output I'd expect to terminal:

```
$ test file.cpp

compile OUTPUT
simulate OUTPUT
```

I would like to be able to redirect the output like so:

```
$ test file.cpp > out_file.txt
```

or:

```
$ test file.cpp | less
```

However, when I try capturing the std output or piping it to less, I only capture the stdout from compile, and the stdout from simulate is NOT even printed to terminal.

How can I capture the stdout from all executed programs with my function?

Comment: Are you sure `simulate` isn't writing to stderr? What's in `stderr.txt` when you run `simulate 2>stderr.txt`?

Comment: Doing this doesn't capture any input.  It prints everything to terminal?

Comment: Excuse me.  I meant to say output.  I believe this is a result of the buffer not being emptied before there is a segfault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that doesn't capture `simulate`'s output then `simulate` isn't writing to stdout. Perhaps it's writing to stderr. You can capture both with:

```
test file.cpp &> out_file.txt
test file.cpp 2>&1 | less
```

(By the way, `test` is a system command so you should probably use a different name.)

Comment: Hmm.  So `test file.cpp &> out_file.txt` prints the stdout, but not the stdinput.      Furthermore, `test file.cpp 2>&1 | less` prints only output from the first program.  Clearly there is something wrong with how simulate prints output, but it is written in C and only uses printf()?

Comment: Perhaps it's writing to `/dev/tty` or `/dev/console`, or doing some other shenanigans. You could use `strace` to see where it's writing to.

Comment: Oh my gosh.  I'm so embarrassed.  My error was a segfault, so the buffer just wasn't being printed before it terminated when I was redirecting.  In my previous comment, I also misspoke and said `stdout` when I meant to say `stderr`, and `stdinput` when I meant `stdout`.

Comment: Is proper etiquette to delete this question, then?